# Solving $x$, $y$ and $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If I have $22x = 23y = 24z$ and $x+y+z = 3865$ how to obtain the values of $x$,$y$ and $z$ ?

Comment: How about substitution?

Comment: Indeed substitution works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $ y = \frac{22}{23}x$ and $z = \frac{22}{24}x$ in last equation.

Answer (score 5):

First, try to express $y$ and $z$ by $x:$

$$22x = 23y\Leftrightarrow y = \frac{22}{23}x$$

$$22x = 24z\Leftrightarrow z = \frac{11}{12}x$$

Then put this into your term to find the value of $x\colon$

$$x+y+z=3865\Leftrightarrow x+\frac{22}{23}x+\frac{11}{12}x=3865$$

Now you have the value of $x.$ To figure out $y$ and $z$ is left as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $ 22x = 23y = 24z $ as three separate equations:

$$ 22x=23y $$ $$ 22x=24z $$ $$ 23y = 24z $$

Then choose one of the three options below:

**Option 1**

Solve for $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x$.

$$ y = \frac{22}{23}x$$

$$ z = \frac{22}{24}x$$

The equation $x + y + z = 3865$ can be rewritten as $$ x + \frac{22}{23}x + \frac{22}{24}x = 3865 $$ Combine like terms to solve for $x$, then use that solution of $x$ to solve for both $y$ and $z$.

**Option 2**

Solve for $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$.

$$ x = \frac{23}{22}y$$

$$ z = \frac{23}{24}y$$

The equation $x + y + z = 3865$ can be rewritten as $$ \frac{23}{22}y + y + \frac{23}{24}y = 3865 $$ Combine like terms to solve for $y$, then use that solution of $y$ to solve for both $x$ and $z$.

**Option 3**

Solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$.

$$ x = \frac{24}{22}z$$

$$ y = \frac{24}{23}z$$

The equation $x + y + z = 3865$ can be rewritten as $$ \frac{24}{22}z + \frac{24}{23}z + z = 3865 $$ Combine like terms to solve for $z$, then use that solution of $z$ to solve for both $x$ and $y$.